# How to access UITableView from delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

When I dismiss a modal, I'm overriding `viewWillAppear` in order to make the table view in the view reload. The problem is that I don't have any pointer to the table view to call it to refresh. I've considered awkward solution such as storing it in a pointer when the tableview first loads and calls the `UIViewController` (the delegate) for each row, but it seems that there hast to be a pointer to it somewhere. Does anyone know how to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very common for a `viewController` with a `UITableView` in it's view hierarchy (even as the root, in the case of a `UITableViewController`) to keep a weak pointer to the `UITableView` for just this kind of thing.

If the `UITableView` is built in `storyboard/xib`, set it up as an `IBOutlet`, otherwise, build the `UITableView` in code, add it as a subview and assign a pointer to `self.tableView`.

`viewWillAppear` is a perfectly sensible place to say `[self.tableView reloadData]`

Comment: An IBOutlet makes perfect sense. I guess I just sort of associated them with textfields and buttons, but forgot that they work for anything. I was thinking that I would have to do some weird thing with `cellForRowAtIndex` to keep track of the table view. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Viral Oh sorry. It originally said that I needed to wait another five minutes and then it just slipped my mind.